# Xcode 4 / gdb / How simply watch object properties?

Tags: xcode, variables, gdb, watch

I am very lost in Xcode 4. Watching a simple variable is a nightmare. I do not figure out how to just "watch a variable value". It was easier in Xcode 3...

I have the following piece of code:

```
if (labelEast.center.x > (east_oldPosition.x + 50) )
        NSLog(@"Time to switch to previous exercise !");
    else if (labelEast.center.x < (east_oldPosition.x - 50) )
        NSLog(@"Time to switch to next exercise !");
```

After setting a breakpoint, I am just trying to watch `labelEast.center.x` (`labelEast` is a `UILabel` object). Since I could not find a watch item in a Xcode 4 menu, I am trying to use gdb. I am used to print variable/object values with `po` (print object). But now, I cannot display `labelEast` `center` property because it is inherited from a mother class.

> (gdb) po labelEast.center
>   There is no member named center.

I do not understand why gdb says this whereas the code works fine and sees the property.

Thus I have 2 questions:

1. How to watch such a property  without gdb in a graphical way (as simply as in Visual Studio) ?
2. How to do the same with gdb ?

Many thanks,
Franz

---

Unfortunately, I tried it but got this:

> po [labelSouth center]
>
> Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
>   Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x1a000356 0x343c7d06 in
>   objc_msgSend_stret () The program being debugged was signaled while in
>   a function called from GDB. GDB remains in the frame where the signal
>   was received. To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on"
>   Evaluation of the expression containing the function (objc_msgSend)
>   will be abandoned.

And when I try:

> (gdb) print labelSouth.center
>   There is no member named center.

I really suspect there is no access to center property in `UILabel`. But how can me code run ???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've hit this thing a few times myself just to remember "oh, that's right, gdb doesn't support dot notation so I have to use getter". Then just do:

```
(gdb) po [myObject someProperty]
```

and all is well with the world again. Also rereading your question I see that you're requesting a non object to be printed, hence you have to give gdb a hint of what type of property you want to print:

```
(gdb) p (CGRect)[myView frame]
(gdb) p (CGPoint)[myView center]
```

and so on.

Comment: (gdb) p (CGRect)[labelSouth center]
$2 = {
  origin = {
    x = 50, 
    y = 26
  }, 
  size = {
    width = 1.23146109e-41, 
    height = 3.88313817e-41
  }
}

Comment: But now, how can we do that simply with Xcode 4 ? I was successfull in opening the debug window but I cannot see any center property for UILabel...

Comment: That's probably because `center` is a property of `UIView` from which `UILabel` inherits. You should look into `superclass` or `parent` or some similar property.

Comment: Finally when I put my pointer to the variable, I can see all properties on a yellow background, but impossible to see the "center" property in it, even when I browse the parent class (UIView)...

Comment: Also struggling with debugging in Xcode 4. This 'powerful' debugger is not easy to use at all. Any helpful answers to looking inside objects in the debugger view?